# VBscript - Body of text file into Email

Tags: email, text, vbscript

i m using the following script to send a few emails during the day, it takes one or more parameters (there are a few versions) and is called by a .bat file. The script is :

```
Const schema   = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
Const cdoBasic = 2
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2
Dim oMsg, oConf
Dim sDateTimeStamp

Set args = WScript.Arguments 
arg1 = args(0)


' E-mail properties
Set oMsg      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
oMsg.From     = "myemail@gmail.com"  ' or "Sender Name <from@gmail.com>"
oMsg.To       = "otheremail@gmail.com"    ' or "Recipient Name <to@gmail.com>"
oMsg.Subject  = "System Message"
oMsg.BodyPart.Charset = "Windows-1253"
oMsg.Textbody = "Attached files." & vbcrlf & _ 
    "This on a new line" & vbcrlf & _ 
    "This on yet another"


Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

Const FileToBeUsed = "DIRTEST.TXT"
Dim fso, f, g
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed, ForReading)

g = f.ReadAll

f.Close

Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing



' GMail SMTP server configuration and authentication info
Set oConf = oMsg.Configuration
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpserver")       = "gmail.com" 'server address
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpserverport")   = 587              'port number
oConf.Fields(schema & "sendusing")        = cdoSendUsingPort
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic         'authentication type
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpusessl")       = False             'use SSL encryption
oConf.Fields(schema & "sendusername")     = "mymy@gmail.com" 'sender username
oConf.Fields(schema & "sendpassword")     = "XXXXXX"      'sender password
oConf.Fields.Update()

'base64

' send message
oMsg.Send()

' Return status message
If Err Then
    resultMessage = "ERROR " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear()
Else
    resultMessage = "Success Notification Message sent succesfully."
End If

Wscript.echo(resultMessage)
```

Right now the text body is set to :

```
    Attached Files
    This is a new line
    This is yet another
```

I would like to interject a directory listing between line 1 and 2, either directly or by saving the directory listing in a text file, then putting the contents of said file in the email body, like so :

```
    Attached Files
    06/10/2016  <TIME>            13.000 Name1.txt
    06/10/2016  <TIME>           300.000 Name2.pdf
    06/10/2016  <TIME>           150.000 Name3.pdf
    06/10/2016  <TIME>         5.000.000 Name4.pdf
    This is a new line
    This is yet another
```

EDIT : The above code succesfully appends the dir list to the mail subject, but also appends a batch of gibberish characters at the top.

Comment: So have you tried placing the directory listing, where's the code for that?...we don't need to see all this. Please see providing a [mcve].

Comment: If i was aware of how to do it, i would obviously not be in the need to ask.

Comment: There is a difference though I asked if you had *"tried"*. Ideally question on [so] need to show a degree of effort on the part of the *asker* to attempt to solve the problem, with an accompanying [mcve] showing where they got to and specific issues they have had *(error messages etc)*. At the moment this fulfills neither and will likely be closed as "Too Broad".

Comment: Just make sure the line `oMsg.Textbody = "Attached files." & vbcrlf & _ 
    "This on a new line" & vbcrlf & _ 
    "This on yet another"` occurs after the pull the directory listing. Add make sure to add `g` into the middle of your `TextBody`.

Comment: You should then have something like `oMsg.Textbody = "Attached files." & vbcrlf & _ 
    g & _
    "This on a new line" & vbcrlf & _ 
    "This on yet another"`

Answer (score 0):

The script is self explanatory

Edit: Formated size. Also note it give the size of folders. This can be slow, you may want to omit for folders. For instance the first time you run above code (on c:\ folder) windows has to read every folder into memory. That takes a while. Second time you run it all folders will be in the disk cache and it will be super fast.

Edit2 The VBS help file has recently been taken down at MS web site. It is available on my skydrive at https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvqkaKIXzvDieQFjUcKneSZhDjw It's called script56.chm.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    On Error Resume Next
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("c:\")

    Set Fls = fldr.files
    Set Fldrs = fldr.subfolders
    For Each thing in Fls
         A= A & vbtab & thing.name & vbtab & thing.attributes & vbtab & FormatNumber(thing.size, 0) & vbtab & Thing.DateLastModified & vbcrlf
    Next
    For Each thing in Fldrs
         A= A & vbtab & thing.name & vbtab & thing.attributes & vbtab & FormatNumber(thing.size, 0) & vbtab & Thing.DateLastModified & vbcrlf
    Next

         msgbox a


             msgbox a
```